# (Re)generate a unique key that passes unique constraint

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I am generating a unique key for a model like so...

```
def changeset(%__MODULE__{} = post, attrs) do
  post
  |> generate_key()
  |> unique_constraint(:key)
end

defp generate_key(changeset) do
  key = :crypto.strong_rand_bytes(5)
  |> Base.url_encode64
  |> binary_part(0, 5)

  put_change(changeset, :key, key)
end
```

This may not be the best way to do this, so feel free to offer other suggestions, but my question is, what would be the best way to re-generate a key when the unique_constraint is hit? And what would be the best way to test that?

EDIT: This isn't exactly the entire schema, it's just condensed to simplify. I actually have a primary ID, as well as some other fields.

I want to have a key that will be publicly shared to different users, with each user having a different key, so it has to be unique. It can be longer than 5 chars, although it will be shared via URL, so I don't want to go too long.  There is a more complex constraint that validates uniqueness based on the key and the email address, so I'm not as worried about the length of 5. Regardless of the length, I want it to be re-generated if the unique_constraint is hit.

Comment: I know nothing about this language but it appear you need that: https://github.com/zyro/elixir-uuid

Comment: Does it need to be restricted to 5 bytes? As @NyamiouTheGaleanthrope suggests, a UUID / `binary_id` field will avoid conflicts by having a much larger key.

Comment: I updated the question, but no it doesn't need to be restricted to 5, just want to make it URL friendly. Although regardless of length, I'd like to regenerate if there ever is a conflict w/ the unique constraint. The UUID lib looks nice, but I was looking for something shorter than that (similiar to youtube's IDs, which I believe used to be 5 chars)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the code I use for creating random strings

```
@spec random_string(integer) :: binary
def random_string(length) do
  length
  |> :crypto.strong_rand_bytes
  |> Base.url_encode64
  |> binary_part(0, length)
end
```

The problem with unique_constraint is that your changeset won't show the constraint error until the write to the datebase is attempted (Repo.insert or Repo.update)

The simplest approach would be to use a separate module to handle the insert. Something like this:

```
defmodule PostService do
  def insert_post(params) do
    changeset = Post.changeset(%Post{}, params)
    case Repo.insert changeset do
      {:error, %{errors: constraint_match}} ->  
        # constraint_error is just a placeholder for the correct match
        insert_post(params)
      error_or_ok -> 
        error_or_ok
    end
  end
end
```

However, if you use a UUID, I don't think you need to worry about collisions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I updated my question to make it a little more clear what I'm looking for. I already have an autogenerated primary ID, unless you think it's ok to have 2 auto-generated IDs? Otherwise, is there a way to have the model automatically re-run your first code block if the unique_constraint is hit?

Comment: I also think you could add a second auto generated binary_id that will be unique. I've never tried it.